# JqGrid - drag & drop - changing page reload grid

Tags: drag-and-drop, jqgrid, paging

I am using drag and drop on `jqgrid` with success. 
So, when I drag a row it disappear from the 1st grid and it appears on the 2nd.
The problem is that if I go to page 2 in the 1st grid and then go back on page 1 the dragged row reappar because the grid will reload.
What's the best way to avoid this?

1. before dropping i can update a hidden field so that the query will not get that row from the DB
2. any way to use paging and load the page just once?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7?

Comment: Hi Tony, i'm using Guriddo jqGrid, last version